# How to write apexmessages in testclass at that step it shows error?

Tags: unit-test

[image]

Controller:

```
public class AccountOppRecords {
public list<opportunity> opplist{set;get;}
public string accname{set;get;}
public string oppstname{set;get;}
public AccountOppRecords(){
}
public void getdata(){
opplist=[select id,name,StageName,Ownerid,Probability from opportunity o where o.stagename=:oppstname and o.account.name=:accname];
if(accname=='' )
{
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please enter Account name'));
}
else
{
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Confirm,'Sucess stagename has entered'));
}
}
}
```

TestClass:

```
@istest
public class AccountOppRecords1_Tc{
static testmethod void AccountOpprecords()
{
list<Opportunity> opplist=new list<Opportunity>();
AccountOppRecords ac= new AccountOppRecords(); 
ac.getdata();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another test method to test the error condition. The exception is thrown if accname is an empty string, so setting that member variable to `''` prior to calling `ac.getData()` should achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to be using String.isBlank instead of == ''.

```
if(String.isBlank(accname))
{
  ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please enter Account name'));
}
else
{
  ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Confirm,'Sucess stagename has entered'));
}
```